# Manipulate plot and sound of a function simultaneously

Tags: plotting, manipulate, sound

I've an amplitude function (see below). I want to manipulate both a plot of this function and the sound it makes with the same sliders.
Is this possible?

```
Manipulate[
  Play[Sin[a t + b t Sin[c t]], {t, 0, 12}], 
  {a, 700 , 40000}, 
  {b, 25, 1000}, 
  {c, 100, 10000}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  your attempt does have a picture of the graph embedded in `Play`.

If you want to do something fancier, say with both `Play` and `Plot`, perhaps something like this:

```
f[t_, a_, b_] := Sin[a t^2 + b t];
Manipulate[
  {Play[f[t, a, b], {t, 0, 12}], 
   Plot[f[t, a, b], {t, 0, .1}, PlotRange -> All]}, {a, 700, 40000}, {b, 25, 1000}]
```

I've only plotted form time `t=0` to `t=0.1` because beyond that, the frequency is too high to see,and it looks like noise.

***WARNING:***  Please turn your speakers *way down* before listening to any of these.